# Making child collapse with parent

Tags: javafx

i will try to expose my problem as good as i can.

This is the XML

```
<VBox fx:id="main" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"
      prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="800.0" style="-fx-background-color: #DEE2E6;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17"
      xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <BorderPane prefHeight="408.0" prefWidth="600.0" VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <left>
            <AnchorPane fx:id="section_to_hide" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                <Label fx:id="hide_btn1" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="54.0" onMouseClicked="#hide" text="Hide me">
                    <font>
                        <Font name="Prompt-Black" size="24.0"/>
                    </font>
                </Label>
            </AnchorPane>
        </left>

        <center>
            <BorderPane fx:id="main_content" prefHeight="442.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                <left>
                    <VBox fx:id="side_section_mails" prefHeight="500.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                        <AnchorPane prefHeight="59.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                            <Label fx:id="hide_btn" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="19.0" onMouseClicked="#hide" text="&lt; Hide it">
                                <font>
                                    <Font name="Prompt-Black" size="24.0"/>
                                </font>
                            </Label>
                        </AnchorPane>
                    </VBox>
                </left>

                <center>
                    <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: #CED4DA;" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER"/>
                </center>
            </BorderPane>
        </center>
    </BorderPane>
</VBox>
```

Controller:

```
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Label hide_btn;

    @FXML
    private AnchorPane section_to_hide;

    @FXML
    private void hide() {
        Animation animation = new Timeline(
                new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300),
                        new KeyValue(section_to_hide.prefWidthProperty(), 0),
                        new KeyValue(section_to_hide.minWidthProperty(), 0)
                )
        );

        animation.play();
    }

    @FXML
    public void initialize() { }
}
```

The problem is: i want the content of the AnchorPane (section_to_hide) to collapse with its parent. Because this is what happens:

https://gyazo.com/41dfc5340a8e4495938cbc43d801fea2

It seems that the label inside the AnchorPane (section_to_hide) does not collapse with the parent.
Is there a way to make it work?

Comment: Using a [`clip`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/17/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Node.html#clipProperty) on the `AnchorPane` (bound to the pane's size) might work for you.

Comment: The behavior you observe is simply a result of using an `AnchorPane` and hard-coding the layout coordinates of the `Label`. The label won't move (because you hard-coded its position), and the contents won't be clipped (see the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/16/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html): *"AnchorPane does not clip its content by default, so it is possible that children's bounds may extend outside its own bounds if the anchor pane is resized smaller than its preferred size."*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

+1 for @Oboe answer. I would like add a bit more to his answer.

If you set managed/visible to false after the animation is finished, you may not see a smooth transition of the label. Means the complete Label is still visible while the pane closes (as in below gif) and gets invisible only after the animation is finished.

[image]

On the other hand, if you bind the clip with the bounds of the section that is hiding, you will get an effect of hiding something with a piece of cover (as in below gif) but not like hiding by sliding the section.
[image]

If the above behaviour is Ok for you, then no issues :). But if your are looking for a peferct sliding animation (as in below gif), you need to add another change of translating the clip position also.

[image]

But for this, you will need to wrap the hiding pane with an extra container.
The end implementation will be :

- Outer container width is reduced to 0
- Hiding container is translated in negative direction
- And the clip is translated in positive direction.

Wrap section_to_hide with StackPane in fxml:

```
<StackPane fx:id="section_to_hide_container" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" alignment="CENTER_LEFT">
    <AnchorPane fx:id="section_to_hide" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: red;" >
        <children>
            <Label fx:id="hide_btn1" layoutX="14.0" layoutY="54.0" onMouseClicked="#hide"
                   text="Hide me">
                <font>
                    <Font name="Prompt-Black" size="24.0"/>
                </font>
            </Label>
        </children>
    </AnchorPane>
</StackPane>
```

And you controller code will change as below:

```
@FXML
private StackPane section_to_hide_container;

@FXML
private void hide() {
    double width = section_to_hide_container.getWidth();
    
    // Create a clip and apply on the pane to hide
    Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();
    clip.setWidth(width);
    clip.heightProperty().bind(section_to_hide.heightProperty());
    section_to_hide.setClip(clip);

    Animation animation = new Timeline(
            new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(300),
                    new KeyValue(section_to_hide_container.prefWidthProperty(), 0),
                    new KeyValue(section_to_hide.translateXProperty(), -width),
                    new KeyValue(clip.translateXProperty(), width)
            )
    );
    animation.setOnFinished(e -> {
        // Removing the clips
        clip.heightProperty().unbind();
        section_to_hide.setClip(null);
        
        //Hiding the panes at the end
        section_to_hide_container.setVisible(false);
        section_to_hide.setVisible(false);
    });
    animation.play();
}

@FXML
public void initialize() {
    // Binding min/max to pref, to not allow the panes width change.
    section_to_hide_container.minWidthProperty().bind(section_to_hide_container.prefWidthProperty());
    section_to_hide_container.maxWidthProperty().bind(section_to_hide_container.prefWidthProperty());
    section_to_hide.minWidthProperty().bind(section_to_hide.prefWidthProperty());
    section_to_hide.maxWidthProperty().bind(section_to_hide.prefWidthProperty());
}
```

I wrote a detailed [blog](https://blog.e-zest.com/sliding-in-javafx-its-all-about-clipping/) about this particular feature. Please do check to get more inputs on this. Also please note that this blog was written almost 10 years back with my knowledge at that time. So some code and wordings may not be relevant now :)

Answer (score 4):

As @James_D noticed in the comments, you should check if an `AchorPane` is the right container for your needs. For the specific example, a `StackPane` may be better suited.

If you need to use an `AchorPane`, one way to hide the pane completely is by applying `.setManaged(false)` to the pane at the end of the animation:

```
animation.setOnFinished(e -> section_to_hide.setManaged(false));
```

As @Slaw noticed in the comments, you can also use a `clip` on the `AnchorPane`:

```
Rectangle clip = new Rectangle();

clip.widthProperty().bind(section_to_hide.widthProperty());
clip.heightProperty().bind(section_to_hide.heightProperty());

section_to_hide.setClip(clip);
```